# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key type: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits

Tags: java, encryption, digital-signature

I want to Sign my data, for that purpose I am using **Windows-MY** keystore and **SunMSAPI** provider for encrypting and decrypting some text using my certificate. But there is Exception:

```
InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key type: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits.
```

on line

```
aesCipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
```

Actually I want to encrypt my data with private key and decrypt with the public key.

My System Configuration is: Windows 7, 64-bit

How to deal with this problem?

My code is this:

```
X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
String serialNumber = c.getSerialNumber().toString();
Key privateKey = (Key) keyStore.getKey(DSCName, null);
Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(DSCName);
DataOutputStream fout = new DataOutputStream(outstream);
  Provider p = keyStore.getProvider();
  String myData = "data to encrypt";
  PublicKey publicKey =  c.getPublicKey();

String cipherText = null;                   
final Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding",keyStore.getProvider().getName());
aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] byteDataToRate = myData.getBytes();
byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteDataToRate);
cipherText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteCipherText);
System.out.println("cipherText:" + cipherText);
// ----------------------------
final Cipher aesCipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding",keyStore.getProvider().getName());
aesCipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, public Key);

byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipher1.doFinal(byteCipherText);
System.out.println(byteDecryptedText);
String decryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);
```

my output is:

```
cipherText:f8/rPxpIgJXILNLSeESOCv2KYj4tomVIASAA45NLmBzA/iOWEsLJvCLYI9+pAqTwx7N8spWP+9HN
ZgaShxGPDjnVkqnuFlzbmXCZUCLMEbSULwzKQsSYMNIDq2x7J376g+GRm8kBYMdgGdNJtMIx8sXP
qvyWxNSWPdhe1xFna1w0DuqK1mR30/ZdU9lACyCMSeXK22K2FM+V7oDR9MHgbpB0oeHfH66emkk0
lpKqu6Wr9D43QwYmXAo/u/8gD3dwr7qdOwarTopfbCLqWfWn8DuyYTwDY/vbdiZJfPZfGNMrnhzq
/tdHm2ScNreskQ8HiMfeH0Iih8MPoiIVac+FVA==
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key type: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23713039584215334199359298536212699709102701257112982501126249760223003496547622902125282473933441681112130016090107773380054108139644420960634826102273499375704409005561487813169118425678603332231931611435818472883984384798084461353789618974581650786153976157396519738737858475541085942135666317196760918526775906883258164847855820472961868914809656826030205995272605151893433820872358865888343062850551910390809733698336903383894285445543225373616943057201233572494941972199152175995644435643142748595739783632001488705350282425460845827015899242784498630928265270728853274152332569674675710858589941739193789787683
  public exponent: 65537
eXCEPTION::
    at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.engineGetKeySize(RSACipher.java:345)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.b(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at EncryptDecrypt.selectActionPerformed(EncryptDecrypt.java:530)
    at EncryptDecrypt.access$3(EncryptDecrypt.java:414)
    at EncryptDecrypt$3.actionPerformed(EncryptDecrypt.java:209)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please reproduce it by a MCVE  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and and come back.

Comment: You encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private. Signature is done the other way around. Do you mean that? If not, then you need  to establish some kind of session key. You need to describe what you want to achieve by editing you question.

Comment: I want to sign some text using this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although signature generation is a similar operation to encryption when using RSA, but Java has different classes that are used for generating signatures.

```
// sign
Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
instance.initSign(privateKey, new SecureRandom());
instance.update(myData.getBytes("UTF-8")); // encoding is important
byte[] signature = instance.sign();

// verify
instance.initVerify(publicKey);
instance.update(myData.getBytes("UTF-8")); // encoding is important
System.out.println(instance.verify(signature));
```

Comment: @ Artjom b: I tried this method also but VERIFICATION fails. Don't know the reason. I think i don't have RSAPrivateKey.

Comment: I forgot the second `getBytes`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the providers and I don't understand what you're doing there, but are you sure that the public key actually corresponds to the private key you're using?

Comment: Good point, I haven't noticed until now that the certificate/public key was fetched with getCertificate(alias) and the private key with getKey(DSCName,...). That might be the same alias or it might be a completely different one, and therefore a different key.

Comment: @ Artjom B: Yes, I am 100% sure that Privatekey and corresponding PublicKey is Correct. Because I am extracting it from  Digital Signature e-Token issued by CA (Certification Authority ) authorized by Government of India.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the exception is that you are using the **SunMSCAPI** provider for a **public key** operation, which is unfortunately not possible.

Just remove the provider parameter in this line of code and it will work:

```
final Cipher aesCipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"); //,keyStore.getProvider().getName());
aesCipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
```

Background info: Your public key is a instance of `sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl` and the Cipher implementation of SunMSCAPI provider only accepts `sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey`. This means that you have to do private key operations with the SunMSCAPI provider and public key operations with the SunJCE provider.

Comment: @Monika Tiwari: You have to remove the provider only before the use of the **public key** in the line with **aesCipher1**. Leave the rest of your code as it is. You cannot convert the private key.

Comment: @ Omikron:If i remove Provider, it gives the following Exception:  java.security.InvalidKeyException: Private keys must be instance of RSAPrivate(Crt)Key or have PKCS#8 encoding.   And by default it is taking   SunJCE Provider.

Comment: @Monika Tiwari Do not remove the provider for the private key operation, only for the public key operation. Change only the line I showed you.

Comment: @ Omikron: When i remove Provider for the public key operation, It gives Exception (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero) at line:                                                                                     byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipher1.doFinal(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(cipherText));

Comment: @MonikaTiwari Ok, that's a new problem. You could try to insert the byte array byteCipherText directly into the second doFinal, just to make sure that the Base64 encoder is not causing it.

Comment: @Omikron: I tried. But this is not making any change.  :-(

Comment: @MonikaTiwari Is the value of the variables `alias` and `DSCName` the same? What happens when you write `X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(DSCName);` instead of `X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(alias);`?

Comment: @Omikron: I am taking alias in DSCName.

Comment: @MonikaTiwari You should use the code from Artjom's answer for signing. If it does not work for you, then create a new question, because this has nothing to do with InvalidKeyException anymore.

Answer (score -2):

@Monika Tiwari, I am facing issue same, i need to sign digital certificate that provided by Goverment of India. I have write the code but not getting the RSAKey value.

```
 KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = CertUtils.getKeyEntryCertificate(alias);//return private key
x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();  
KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = xmlSignatureFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
List x509Content = new ArrayList();
x509Content.add(x509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
x509Content.add(x509Certificate);
X509Data x509Data = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509Content);
KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(x509Data));
document = documentBuildFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputFile);
DOMSignContext domSignContext = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(),
document.getDocumentElement());
XMLSignature signature = xmlSignatureFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo);
signature.sign(domSignContext);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Writing output xml file");
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
outputStream = objHttpServerConnection.writeFileFromHttpServer(objParam.getInputFilePath());
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(outputStream));
```

Please check the code, in signed data have not the details of keyValue and RSAKeyValue tags. In output signed xml file have only keyInfo value with signatre tag.

Comment: You have seen that the last posting of Monika Tiwari here was in Jan. 2015 and she was last active on SO: Last seen Mar 6 at 10:58 ? So probably it's the best to ask your own question with some sample data as well.